Como hacer para que webstorm no utilice WSL
Estoy usando webstorm en windows
El problema es: Webstorm intenta correr comandos usando una ruta de WSL.

Webstorm intenta correr el comando usando:
/mnt/c/Users/..../WebstormProjects/..../node_modules/.bin/nest
Lo cual es una ruta que parece de WSL, lo raro es que antes funcionaba usando la ruta normal "C:/Users..." pero de un momento a otro dejó de funcionar

Estas usando la terminal de windows integrada a webstorm? No conozco mucho sobre webstorm, pero al parecer todo tu proyecto (incluido los binarios de nodejs) están instalados en windows. Si vas a usar wsl, tu proyecto debería estar dentro de wsl y tu instalación de nodejs también, de esa manera no tendrías problemas.

si, todo está instalado en windows y quiero usar windows. pero por algún motivo webstorm insiste en usar wsl. en webstorm estoy usando la terminal de git bash que tambien está instalada en windows
